# Offscreen rendering with QQuickFramebufferObject

Tags: qt, opengl

I'm trying to experiment with offscreen rendering with QQuickFramebufferObject. It appears that I cannot do it -- if I try to bind a FBO to render offscreen, the framebuffer ends up being permanently blue after I release the FBO and attempt to render to the framebuffer.

To make sharing code easier, I've uploaded an example to https://github.com/sohailshafii/textureinsgnode_offscreen. It is basically the "textureinsgnode" Qt example modified to include a FBO that can be rendered to. Right now in the render function of fboinsgrenderer (https://github.com/sohailshafii/textureinsgnode_offscreen/blob/master/fboinsgrenderer.cpp) I disable offscreen rendering:

```
// uncomment this block of code to see an incorrect rendering
    /*m_fbo->bind();
    logo.render();
    update();
    m_fbo->release();
    m_fbo->bindDefault();*/
    logo.render();
    update();
```

But once I uncomment the FBO here, I get a solid blue screen. I've viewed offscreen rendering examples in QT but unfortunately they don't describe how it's done with QQuickFramebufferObject. I'm running QT 5.7.1.